# ms access vba save button not function

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm having a problem here ( very simple problem but I cant solve it). I'm having save button on the form that use vba codes to save the record (Do.Cmd.Save), But sadly it's not function. Hereby I put the codes below. Advance thanks for your kindly help!

```
Private Sub Command110_Click()

'Provide the user with the option to save/undo
'changes made to the record in the form

If MsgBox("Changes have been made to this record." _
    & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Do you want to save these changes?" _
    , vbYesNo, "Changes Made") = vbYes Then
        DoCmd.Save
    Else
        DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdUndo
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

`DoCmd.Save` saves changes to an Access object (e.g. a query or form definition).

To save a record, use

```
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
```